# Passenger + Nginx : Problem with xml routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am trying to migrate from `nginx + mongrel` to `nginx + passenger`. The app loads and works but I can't get it to identify routes like `/posts/100.xml`. However, urls like `/posts/100?format=xml` work

Is there some configuration that I am missing?

Thanks,
Prateek

Comment: Nothing really stands out. Can you please post your nginx config? Also, Have you verified that the desired URL structure is working fine in another environment?

Answer (score 2):

It was a redirect rule to redirect all non slash urls to slash ones that was messing things up. Sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

check this line on `routes.rb`

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. From the rails 3.x routes.rb: "This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications."